# asp.net web api: action filter attribute is thread-safe by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

Can some one confirm me that asp.net web api action filters are singleton/instance based by default? In asp.net core, I observed that it has one instance by default and the method is as per request-based. I am not sure on wweb.api action filters. Sorry if this question sounds silly.

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
namespace SampleApp.Attributes
{
    public class CustomAttribute: Attribute, IActionFilter
    {
         public CustomAttribute()
         {
          // resolves dependencies here
         }

         public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
         {
              // some code goes here with some update operations in sql server stored procedure level
         }
    }          
}
```

Comment: Can some one update on this please? Its a priority one. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Filters aren't singletons, but are single instance because of the way they are registered.  config.Filters.Add(new yourfilter()); is called only one once at startup, so there is only 1 instance of a filter.

Answer (score 0):

As it states in the Microsoft documentation for filters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#thread-safety):

> When passing an instance of a filter into Add, instead of its Type, the filter is a singleton and is not thread-safe.

If you're registering the filter type (rather than an instance), the framework will indeed create a new instance of the filter per request.

Comment: I don't believe the question is talking about .NET Core / .NET 6+, but instead [ASP.NET 4.x Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api), given the text, "In asp.net core, I observed ... [X, but] I am not sure on wweb.api [sic] action filters." That, and the docs for `ExecuteActionFilterAsync` were written in 2015, a year before the release of .NET Core. Does the same advice still apply?

Comment: If that is the case, at this point it is probably easier to just try it for yourself rather than seek out the relevant framework docs. A simple GetHashCode comparison of the filter between requests will give you the truth of it